# Setting kwargs for train_test_split

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keyword-argument, iterable-unpacking

I have a notebook that iterates over the same model, with increasing features. I'd like to simply fill out the `train_test_split()` with a dict of the relevant args, rather than filling it out each time. For my Random Forest model, for example, I've created a hyperparameter dict:

```
rf_params = {
    'class_weight':'balanced',
    'max_depth':2,
    'n_estimators':1000,
    'n_jobs':-1,
    'random_state':42
}
```

I'll unpack that with each random forest classifier: `rf_clf = RandomForestClassifier(**rf_params)`. I'd like to do the same with `train_test_split()`, whose arguments will always be `X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42`, but upon examining the docs, it appears that the standard call for `X` and `y` is not a kwarg, but rather based on `*arrays`. How do I set that in a dict to unpack?

Something along the lines of

```
split_args = {
    '*arrays':['X','y'],
    'test_size':0.3,
    'random_state':42
 }

train_test_split(**split_args)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*args` for that:

```
split_args = [X, y]
split_kwargs = {
    'test_size':0.3,
    'random_state':42
}

train_test_split(*split_args, **split_kwargs)
```

Since `*arrays` is positional only, it needs to be passed as an iterable instead of a dict.

See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Is there a way to set the `*args` as part of the dict for `**kwargs`, or am I just getting too fancy for my own good?

Comment: positional-only arguments can't be part of kwargs - so no.